# Using Tooltip with GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: geographics

I am using GeoRegionValuePlot to create color coded county maps of a given state.  Color is determined from the value given with a rule.  I would like that same value specified in the rule to be displayed when I mouse-click on the county as displayed in the GeoRegionValuePlot graph.  Nothing I have read in the documentation gives me any idea on how to do this or whether it can be done.  I can't find any examples of Tooltip used along with Geo maps.

My current GeoRegionValuePlot is given below:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[countyRules, PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Black}]], ImageSize ->500, GeoBackground -> None, GeoProjection -> {"LambertAzimuthal"},PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Where countyRules is a list of county entity rules for all counties of the state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  [`Tooltip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) as the setting for the option [`GeoLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoLabels.html):

```
countriesandvalues = {Entity["Country", "France"] -> 3, 
   Entity["Country", "Germany"] -> 1, Entity["Country", "Italy"] -> 8};

GeoRegionValuePlot[countriesandvalues, 
 GeoLabels -> (Tooltip[#, Row[{CommonName@#2, " :", #4}]] &)]
```

[image]

**Note:** [GeoRegionValuePlot >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRegionValuePlot.html)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works Perfectly.  Thanks!